# How to search specific tasklist processes in depth using Java?

Tags: java, runtime, tasklist

I'm trying to search the tasklist using Java to find out whether a specific program is running on a person's computer. I have everything working fine except for the fact that it can easily be bypassed by changing the process name, or spoofing the name.

Is there anyway I can actually go a bit more in-depth with the task, like reading some of the memory of the program to recognise it, or do programs have a UID/PID anywhere that I can use to identify it? Cause searching by name is useless.

Any other solutions?

Edit: Forgot to mention, this is not just for Java applications. It's the whole task list including .exe files etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the jps tool for tracking java processes. Link:     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html

If you would like to know the dependent exe, dlls, files used by a process, then process explorer would help you. Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's not just Java applications I'm searching for

Comment: @Kieran: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm looking to do this through Java code and not a separate program. I can scan the processes for the name, but I can't get anything more detailed about the process and that's ultimately what I need.